# Comparing specific locations in arrays. Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking to create a method that compares a specific location of two 2D arrays, assuming both arrays have the same row and column. I want to have a method that passes in as arguments, an array at specific location( i.e. int[3][1] array) and compare that array to my already set array. I kind of have an idea of maybe creating a whole new array and setting the specific location into that array and then comparing both the arrays as a whole, but I'm not too sure about that.

Comment: What do the arrays contain?

Comment: Well my already set array is initialed to 0 except for one spot and I want to check that one spot.

Comment: What code have you written till now?

Comment: Won't `a[3][1] == b[3][1]` not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to override method `equals()` and `hashCode` for array content.

```
public class Essence {
class SpecialArray{
 public <?> [3][3] array;

@Override
public int hashCode() { // eclipse can generate this two methods 
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
}


}
SpecialArray a = new SpecialArray();
SpecialArray b = new SpecialArray();
a.array[1][1] = x;// value
b.array[1][1] = x;// value
    a.equals(b); // true
}
```